# Transform AWS Cloud formation templates contents to java objects

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I would like to transform the cloud formation template(JSON) contents to JAVA objects. The cloud formation templates have AWS functions(fn:GetAtt,fn:Select etc.,) as well. I am looking for a library which transforms it to JAVA objects.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: What is the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am planning to get the list of resources and its properties from the JSON, run some tests on the resources to get some data

Comment: Will it be sufficient to parse into a hierarchy of maps and lists? If yes then you can use the Jackson Object Mapper. Otherwise, I think it's very unlikely that you'll find anything that supports going _from_ CloudFormation to Java.

Comment: The SDK describeStackResources() method will return a list of all resources created in a given CloudFormation stack.

Comment: Bisque does it in dotnet....  https://www.nuget.org/packages/YadaYada.Bisque.Aws/  Use Template.Load()